# remove control, hidden, unwanted characters from string

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

please before I get hammered because there are other stackoverflow questions like mine but they do not work.  I am trying to remove unwanted characters from an inbound message without success. I do not know what the characters are or represent, however, they seem to break the data up like carriage returns and line feeds or new lines. 
I need to keep all the spaces except those at the end.
the characters I see are ^M and ^C. sometimes used together, and alone.

my test code basically from observing other similar questions.

```
String msg = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

log.info("Message before apply filter: " + msg);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]","");
log.info("Remove non-ASCII characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("[\\p{C}]","");
log.info("Remove all Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}\\p{Co}\\p{Cn}]","");
log.info("Remove some Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","");
log.info("Remove non printable characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = msg.trim();
log.info("Trim: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("\\cM","");
log.info("Remove ^M Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("^M","");
log.info("Remove ^M Control characters: " + filteredMessage);

exchange.getIn().setBody(filteredMessage);
```

Sample data files:

```
A   291511191831421742XXXXXXXXXXWRN/WN18111917420077000009ENG 2 IGN B FAULT^M ^C

A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

A   080011191830061749XXXXXXXXXXMPF/AN.N306DN/FIDAL800    /DM181119142800/DAKSMF/DSKMSP/WN18111916310034000006NAV ATC/XPDR 1 FAULT^M,18111917480032000009BRAKES HOT^M/FR18111916310034523306ATC 1(1SH1)^M/IDATC 1^M/FR18111916310034723406ATC1(1SH1)/TCAS(1000SG)^M/IDTCAS^M/FR18111917120022833406AFS:FMGC2^M/IDAFS 1^M,IR 1^M,IR 2^M,IR 3^M/FR18111917120022833406AFS:FMGC1^M/IDAFS 1^M,IR 1^M,IR 2^M,IR 3^M ^C
```

My filters are not working. here is the results. it's like the regex is not working at all or I'm doing something silly. thanks everyone!

```
 Message before apply filter: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Remove non-ASCII characters: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Remove all Control characters: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Remove some Control characters: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Remove non printable characters: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Trim: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Remove ^M Control characters: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C

Remove ^M Control characters: A   056611191832641742XXXXXXXXXXFLR/FR18111917410032470002BRK TEMP SENSOR4(6GW)/  BTMU(2GW)^M/IDBSCU 1^M  ^C
```

Comment: "there are other stackoverflow questions like mine but they do not work" - can you link to them so we know which ones you've tried? There's probably more

Comment: If you want to remove literal `^M` you have to escape the `^` metachar `\^M`

Comment: You should be successively applying your filters on `filteredMessage`, not on the original `msg`.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/tLFW5x/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and see how it goes:

```
String msg = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

log.info("Message before apply filter: " + msg);
filteredMessage = msg.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]","");
log.info("Remove non-ASCII characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage =filteredMessage.replaceAll("[\\p{C}]","");
log.info("Remove all Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = filteredMessage.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}\\p{Co}\\p{Cn}]","");
log.info("Remove some Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = filteredMessage.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","");
log.info("Remove non printable characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = filteredMessage.trim();
log.info("Trim: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = filteredMessage.replaceAll("\\cM","");
log.info("Remove ^M Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
filteredMessage = filteredMessage.replaceAll("^M","");
log.info("Remove ^M Control characters: " + filteredMessage);
```

After this, if you still see characters you dont want, you need to use the escape character `\` to escape backslashes and other metacharacters:

`<>()[]{}\^-=$!|?*+.`

So you need, for example : `.replaceALl("\^M","");`

Comment: Strings are immutable. `filteredMessage.replaceAll("[\\p{C}]","");` returns *new* string based on one from `filteredMessage` which you are discarding. It doesn't affect original one which will still be held by `filteredMessage`. If you want to apply all filters on `filteredMessage` you need to add `filteredMessage = ...`.

Comment: thanks everyone. really appreciate it.  yeah, I was simply attempting to try the regex on the original message to see the results on just that regex.  I will try this and get back.

Comment: I still don't get it.  How do you find out just what these are, ^M^C ?  nothing works. I took both suggestions and implemented.  the only thing that works is literally stating .replaceAll("\\^M","") and .replaceAll("\\^C","").  I am led to believe that filtering control sequence characters would work, but it doesn't.